# CPU core number of debugged thread

Tags: c++, debugging, winapi, cpu

Platform: Windows 10

Toolchain: MSVC2017

Is there an ability to see which CPU core where some thread is a running (pinned by assigning affinity mask) on, in the debugger or any other utility like Process Explorer (Sysinernals)?

Comment: `the number of the core where some thread is a running in the debugger?` I don't understand the number of cores you need. Could you give some detailed instructions, code or screenshots, etc. for what you need.

Comment: sorry for incorrect question , fixed this

Comment: You can display a thread's [Affinity Mask](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/debugger/walkthrough-debugging-a-multithreaded-application?view=vs-2017#use-the-threads-window) in the Threads window. If you confined the respective thread to a single core, then that's the information you are looking for.